# Having trouble showing the correct answer in javascript quiz

Tags: javascript

I'm playing around with a simple javascript quiz where the user gets to answer some questions and at the end I want to show the user their score and which answers were wrong. It doesn't work though and I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

This is my code at the moment: https://codepen.io/tydh/pen/RwWPVEP

```
function submitAnswers() {

    const form = document.forms["quizForm"];                 
    form.addEventListener("submit", submitAnswers);

    function submitAnswers(e) { e.preventDefault();

    var total = 5;
    var score = 0;

    // get user input

    var q1 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q1"].value;
    var q2 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q2"].value;
    var q3 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q3"].value;
    var q4 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q4"].value;
    var q5 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q5"].value;

    // set correct answers

    var answers = ['b', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'd'];    

    // check answers (note i - 1 to account for array starting with [0])

    for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++) { const answer = answers[i - 1];

    if (form['q' + i].value == answer) {
        const label = document.querySelector('#q' + i + answer + ' label');
        label.style.color = 'green';
        score++;
    }

    // display results

    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    results.innerHTML ='<h3>You got <span> '+score+' </span> out of <span>'+total+'</span> </h3>';
    alert('You got '+score+' out of '+total); 

}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" ? can't you be more specific ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error in your function and need to call in input.

```js
function submitAnswers() { 


  var total = 5;
    var score = 0;

    // get user input
    var form=document.querySelector("form");
    var q1 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q1"].value;
    var q2 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q2"].value;
    var q3 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q3"].value;
    var q4 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q4"].value;
  var q5 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q5"].value;

  // set correct answers

    var answers = ['b', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'd'];    

    // check answers (note i - 1 to account for array starting with [0])

    for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++) { const answer = answers[i - 1];

        if (form['q' + i].value == answer) {
            const label = document.querySelector('#q' + i + answer + ' label');
            label.style.color = 'green';
            score++;
        }
     }

    // display results

    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    results.innerHTML ='<h3>You got <span> '+score+' </span> out of         <span>'+total+'</span> </h3>';
    alert('You got '+score+' out of '+total);
}
```

```html
  <div id="container">
   <header>
    <h1> Simple JavaScript Quiz</h1>
    <p> Test your knowledge in <strong>JavaScript fundamentals</strong></p>
   </header>
   <section>
    <div id="results"> </div>

    <form name="quizForm">

    <h3>1. In which elements do we put in JavaScript code?</h3>
    <div id="q1a"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="a"><label>a. &lt;js&gt;</label></div>
    <div id="q1b"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="b"><label>b. &lt;script&gt;</label></div>
    <div id="q1c"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="c"><label>c. &lt;body&gt;</label></div>
    <div id="q1d"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="d"><label>d. asd</label></div>

    <h3>2. Which HTML attribute is used to reference an external JavaScript file?</h3>
    <div id="q2a"><input type="radio" name="q2" value="a"><label>a. src</label></div>
    <div id="q2b"><input type="radio" name="q2" value="b"><label>b. rel</label></div>
    <div id="q2c"><input type="radio" name="q2" value="c"><label>c. type</label></div>
    <div id="q2d"><input type="radio" name="q2" value="d"><label>d. href</label></div>

    <h3>3. How would you write "Hello" in an alert box?</h3>
    <div id="q3a"><input type="radio" name="q3" value="a"><label>a. msg("Hello");</label></div>
                <div id="q3b"><input type="radio" name="q3" value="b"><label>b. alertBox("Hello");</label></div>
                <div id="q3c"><input type="radio" name="q3" value="c"><label>c. document.write("Hello");</label></div>
                <div id="q3d"><input type="radio" name="q3" value="d"><label>d. alert("Hello");</label></div>


    <h3>4. JavaScript is directly related to "Java" Programming language?</h3>
                <div id="q4a"><input type="radio" name="q4" value="a"><label>a. True</label></div>
    <div id="q4b"><input type="radio" name="q4" value="b"><label>b. False</label></div>
   

    <h3>5. A variable in JavaScript must start with which special character?</h3>
                <div id="q5a"><input type="radio" name="q5" value="a"><label>a. @</label></div>
                <div id="q5b"><input type="radio" name="q5" value="b"><label>b. $</label></div>
                <div id="q5c"><input type="radio" name="q5" value="c"><label>c. #</label></div>
                <div id="q5d"><input type="radio" name="q5" value="d"><label>d. No Special</label></div>
                <br>

    <input type="button"onclick="submitAnswers()" value="Submit Answers"/> <br><br>

    </form>
   </section>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the same name for sumitAnswer in two scopes, so you probably get function shadowing, as an internal function only prevents default and rest of code is never executed.
Basically what happens here is:

1. File is loaded and submitAnswer() is hoisted in global scope
2. Inside of it, there is scope of function submitAnswer that has it's own function submitAnswer(e) that only prevents default.
3. You never invoked submitAnswer() so none of code was executed

Try this

```
    const form = document.forms["quizForm"];                 
    form.addEventListener("submit", submitAnswers);

    function submitAnswers(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        var total = 5;
        var score = 0;

        // get user input

        var q1 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q1"].value;
        var q2 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q2"].value; 
        var q3 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q3"].value;
        var q4 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q4"].value;
        var q5 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q5"].value;

        // set correct answers

        var answers = ['b', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'd'];    

        // check answers (note i - 1 to account for array starting with [0])

        for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++) { const answer = answers[i - 1];
            if (form['q' + i].value == answer) {
                const label = document.querySelector('#q' + i + answer + ' label');
                label.style.color = 'green';
                score++;
            }
        }

        // display results

        var results = document.getElementById("results");
        results.innerHTML ='<h3>You got <span> '+score+' </span> out of <span>'+total+'</span> </h3>';
        alert('You got '+score+' out of '+total);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing `}` in your `for` loop.

```js
const form = document.forms["quizForm"];                  
form.addEventListener("submit", submitAnswers);
function submitAnswers(e) { 

  e.preventDefault();
  var total = 5;
    var score = 0;

    // get user input

    var q1 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q1"].value;
    var q2 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q2"].value;
    var q3 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q3"].value;
    var q4 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q4"].value;
  var q5 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q5"].value;

  // set correct answers

    var answers = ['b', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'd'];    

    // check answers (note i - 1 to account for array starting with [0])

    for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++) { const answer = answers[i - 1];

        if (form['q' + i].value == answer) {
            const label = document.querySelector('#q' + i + answer + ' label');
            label.style.color = 'green';
            score++;
        }
     }

    // display results

    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    results.innerHTML ='<h3>You got <span> '+score+' </span> out of         <span>'+total+'</span> </h3>';
    alert('You got '+score+' out of '+total);
}
```